# Zip package with Unicode chars in file name can't be uncompressed with System.IO.Packaging.Package?

Tags: c#, unicode, in-memory, system.io.packaging

Have some troubles with file package manipulation.

Here is short description of issue:

If a package contains a file with Unicode characters in it, compressing of it works well(can open package and be uncompressed it in windows) but if try to use this Package.Open(.., FileMode.Open), it results in error "File contains corrupted data".

Question: What am i doing wrong? Can't figure this out. Please advise.

Here is code for compressing and uncompromising binary data in-memory that i use:

```
public virtual byte[] UnZipFile(byte[] data, string packageFileName)
{
    using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var package = Package.Open(inputStream, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var fileUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(@"/" + packageFileName, UriKind.Relative));

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var partStream = package.GetPart(fileUri).GetStream())
                {
                    partStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }
                return outputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

public virtual byte[] ZipFile(byte[] data, string packageFileName)
{
    using (var outMs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var package = Package.Open(outMs, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var fileUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(@"/" + packageFileName, UriKind.Relative));
            var contentType = @"data/" + packageFileName.Substring(packageFileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
            using (var zipStream = package.CreatePart(fileUri, contentType, CompressionOption.Normal).GetStream())
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    ms.CopyTo(zipStream);
                }
            }
        }
        return outMs.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Zip support is clumsy, it only supports Encoding.ASCII for the filename.  Use the .NET 4.5 System.IO.Compression namespace or a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by using newer lib, System.IO.Compression, thanks for pointing out this @Hans Passant